# Child Component not rendering with change in props in svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have created a store in svelte like:

```
const initalStore: FileDetailsPayload  = {
        jobID: 0,
        jobName: "",
        lastUploadInfo: {
          status: "",
          rowDetails: [],
          uploadTableData: {
             columns: [],
             data: []
          }
};


function CreateStore() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(initalStore);

    return {
        subscribe,
        set: (fileDetailList) => set(fileDetailList),
    };
}

export const fileDetailStore = CreateStore();
```

Now I am calling an API to set the store value, and I have subscribed the store in my component A.

```
const unsubscribe = fileDetailStore.subscribe((value) => {
        fileDetailsData = {...value};
    });
```

I am using the `fileDetailsData` in a child component `Table` which I am calling from Component A.

```
<Table tableData={fileDetailsData.uploadTableData} />
```

**Issue:** Whenever I am setting the new data in the store the store is getting updated and can see the updated value of store inside component A, But the child component which is `Table` is not getting re-rendered when the prop is changing.
So overall I want my child component to get re-rendered on any change in props

**Solution** The problem was in the child component Table, where the local variables were not made reactive to the props.

Earlier: Table Component

```
<script>
export let tableData: TableData = { columns: [], data: [] };

    let columnData = tableData.columns || [];
    let rowData = tableData.data || [];
    let rowDataCopy = rowData.slice();
</script>
<div>
// using columnData and rowDataCopy
</div>
```

Now: Table Component

```
<script>
    export let tableData: TableData = { columns: [], data: [] };
    
    $: columnData = tableData.columns || [];
    $: rowData = tableData.data || [];
    $: rowDataCopy = rowData.slice();
    </script>
    <div>
    // using columnData and rowDataCopy
    </div>
```

Comment: You generally don't need `subscribe` in components, just use [`$store` to access the value](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values).

Comment: Show the code of `Table`, it might not be using the property `tableData` correctly (losing reactivity).

Comment: This has been resolved, the issue was with the reactivity of the variables used in Child Component. Thanks for the hunch.

Comment: Please either add the code causing the issue to the question, post an answer explaining the problem & accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not problem with svelte, it's that reference for `uploadTableData` is not changing, understand when you are doing `{...value}` you are changing the root reference but not the inner reference.

You need to deep clone the whole object of filedetails -

Use `structuredClone` or hack it by stringifying and parsing

[structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

```
  const unsubscribe = fileDetailStore.subscribe((value) => {
        fileDetailsData = structuredClone(value);
    });
```

or

```
  const unsubscribe = fileDetailStore.subscribe((value) => {
                fileDetailsData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
            });
```

Comment: I tried the above 2 suggestions but the issue still persist which is my child component <Table/> is not getting re-rendered and hence the table values are not changing. Earlier also, I was getting the updated store value in ```fileDetailsData``` . Any possible reason why <Table/> is not getting re-rendered when ```fileDetailsData``` is updating?